# Can I create the db while the user is installing the apk file

Tags: android

Currently, after installation, when the user open the application for the first time, the app will create the db and load the data.
Can I do this job while the apk installation?

Comment: No, you can't. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Geobits said, it not possible. The earlier that you can run a code is at the Application startup (a class that extends `Application`), just before your first activity is opened. The installation process is not part of your app, it's an OS process, and you can't interact with it.